# background pic 2 scenarios - 1 height is big, other is small

Tags: css

I have 2 scenarios of background picture in a navbar (I think that is where it is located - I am a beginner w/css).

The height of the background image in the following is big:

```
.navbar-brand { 
  font-size:1.5em
}
header {
  background-image: url(../../images/backpic.jpg);
  background-repeat: none;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff
}
```

The height of the background image in this second one is small:

```
.navbar-default.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand { 
  font-size:1.5em
}
header {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(../../images/backpic.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I am trying to make the height of the second one, just a little bigger, but not as big as the first one.

I also want to add a nice container in the under the middle left part of the navbar i.e. the "ASDFADF" lettering part.

Any help would be great..

Comment: Hi Beth, can you add some of your HTML so we can help you solve the problem? If possible, show a visual representation to assist us in answering your question. I'll hazard a guess below, in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, let's clean up your styling a little bit. All the background properties that you've declared can be combined into one shorthand called `background`. Here's your code cleaned up:

```
.navbar-brand { 
  font-size:1.5em
}
header {
  background: url(../../images/backpic.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff
}
```

The `background-size` no longer requires vendor prefixes and can be combined into the above declaration.

Next, to increase the size of the second image background, do the following:

```
.navbar-default.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand { 
  font-size:1.5em
}
header.smaller {
  background: url(../../images/backpic.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
  background-size: 125%; /* Adjust this value to the desired size */
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

You'll want to add a different class to the second container so you can target that separately (since they both use the same base element selector).